# how use Bootstrap File Input with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, bootstrap-file-input

I am using Bootstrap File Input and this work fine but when i tried to get the data files in jsp, I can,t do it this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type = "text / javascript" ></script>  
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type = "text / javascript" > </script> 
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/fileinput.min.js" ></script> 
        <script src="vendor/kartik-v-bootstrap-fileinput-v5.0.7-0-g4a656ec/kartik-v-bootstrap-fileinput-4a656ec/js/locales/es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="file-loading">
            <input id="input-ficons-3" name="input-ficons-3[]" multiple type="file">
        </div>
                    <div class="file-loading">
            <input id="input-ficons-4" name="xml[]" multiple type="file" accept=".xml">
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#input-ficons-4").fileinput({
                language: "es",
                uploadUrl: "/pruebasjavaweb/grabar.jsp",
                previewFileIcon: '<i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>',
                allowedPreviewTypes: null, // disable preview of standard types
                showCaption: true,
                showRemove: false,
                showClose: false,
                showZoom: false,
                //allowedPreviewMimeTypes: ['image/jpeg', 'text/javascript'], // allow content to be shown only for certain mime types 
                previewFileIconSettings: {
                    'xml': '<i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i>',
                    'XML': '<i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i>',
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but i have problem when tried recover the files that i send

Comment: Welcome, I see you are new to the site. Can you please add more details about the files?  Were they corrupted from the original format? Did they just not download? More details can help with an appropriate answer.

Comment: ok I **send** the data to the **url** with the property **uploadUrl: "/pruebasjavaweb/grabar.jsp"** but in **grabar.jsp** I can´t access to **xml[]** with **request.getParameterValues("xml[]").**